# How to get python zookeeper api to work?

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to get zookeeper to work in standalone mode for python api testing and am having issues with the python api.

1) Here is how I installed on ubuntu 11.04

```
sudo apt-get install zookeeper
sudo easy_install zc-zookeeper-static
from source install python zc.zk
http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zc.zk/zc.zk-0.9.1.tar.gz
```

2) Here is how I start zookeeper:

```
sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2181(CONNECTING) 0]
```

3) Here is how I try and using the python api per the docs.

```
import zc.zk
zk = zc.zk.ZooKeeper('localhost:2181')
zk.register_server('/fooservice/providers', ('192.168.0.42', 8080))
```

4) Here is the python error I get.

```
No handlers could be found for logger "ZooKeeper"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/zookeeper/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    zk = zc.zk.ZooKeeper('localhost:2181')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc.zk-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/zc/zk/__init__.py", line 211, in __init__
    raise FailedConnect(connection_string)
zc.zk.FailedConnect: localhost:2181
```

5) Here is the log file:

```
2012-07-15 14:23:51,666 - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1000] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2012-07-15 14:23:51,667 - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1120] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1078)
2012-07-15 14:23:53,076 - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1000] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2012-07-15 14:23:53,077 - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@908] - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2012-07-15 14:23:53,165 - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1114] - Unable to reconnect to ZooKeeper service, session 0x0 has expired, closing socket connection
```

So...I am new to zookeeper.  I would like to get up and running in standalone mode with the python api.  Alos, there seems top be a lot of python zookeeper api's.  Which one is the most used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using IPv6 on your ubuntu? Replace localhost to 127.0.0.1, the same as used in zkCli.sh command. You can run `sudo netstat -lnp|grep 2181` to check the address which the zookeeper listen on.

Comment: Here are the results: sudo netstat -lnp|grep 2181  I got nothing.  Like its not even running.  How do I check if i am using IPv6?

Comment: It's weird. If the zookeeper is running, you will see some like `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12682/java`
use `sudo netstat -lnp|grep java` and `sudo ps aux|grep java|grep zookeeper` to check your zookeeper process

Comment: sudo ps aux|grep java|grep zookeeper
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
root     21831  0.3  1.9 1054176 31108 pts/2   Sl+  14:07   0:22 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,ROLLINGFILE -cp /etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain -server 127.0.0.1:2181

Comment: sudo netstat -lnp|grep java
tcp6       0      0 :::7333                 :::*                    LISTEN      4199/java

Comment: It seems the zookeeper not running correctly. Check the log, location is /var/log/zookeeper/zookeeper.log, and restart the zookeeper. You could find the exact address which zookeeper listen on in the log.

Comment: Hi...I placed the log file output in the question.  Seems that it cant connect to that port for some reason.